# Activity diagram decision label jumps to default position

Tags: enterprise-architect

When I open my Enterprise Architect activity diagram, the decision labels jump to the default position. When I select all elements (ctrl+A), then the decision labels jump to the position where I had dragged (and saved) them.
Seems like a bug...
Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Just tested in v16.1 and I don't see that problem. In which version do you have this problem?

Comment: Any add-ins you have enabled. Also: what do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: version 15.2.156

Comment: none that i know of

Comment: jump: I drag the labels to the left , I close the diagram, I open the diagram, the labels are at their default position in the center

Comment: I'll try that with my V15 later. Guess that Geert used V16. You should edit the explanation in the question.

Comment: Well, no. When closing EA asks to save the changes and it just works. I usesd 15.2.1560

Comment: problem is no longer reproducible. thanks for your help.